# how do i fix the issue with my flutter project, when ever i run flutter pub get it resulted to this issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-pub, pubspec.yaml, flutter-pubspec

Resolving dependencies...
Because no versions of flutter_secure_storage_windows match 1.1.3 and no versions of flutter_secure_storage_windows match >1.1.3 <2.0.0, flutter_secure_storage_windows ^1.1.3 is forbidden.
So, because fstore depends on flutter_secure_storage ^7.0.1 which depends on flutter_secure_storage_windows ^1.1.3, version solving failed.
pub get failed

I tried changing the flutter_secure_storage_windows version to the latest version but still didn't work for me

Comment: Since "flutter_secure_storage" package has a dependency to "flutter_secure_storage_windows" package, try removing "flutter_secure_storage_windows" from pubspec.yaml and try pub get again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any`

```
dependencies:
  flutter_secure_storage: any
```

Having tighter constraints makes it easier for `packages get`/`packages upgrade` to search matching versions because it reduces the solution space